# Sorting numbers but in HTML within UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I've been trying to sort html based on decimal numbers but failing miserably.
My HTML code is:

```
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-value="8" title="8">8</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="9" title="9">9</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="10" title="10">10</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="11" title="11">11</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="12" title="12">12</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="13" title="13">13</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="14" title="14">14</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="8.5" title="8.5">8.5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="9.5" title="9.5">9.5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="10.5" title="10.5">10.5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="11.5" title="11.5">11.5</a></li>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Add this block of javascript code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     function arrangeLiBasedOnDataValue() {
        $('li').sort(sort_li) // sort elements
                .appendTo('ul');
        }
     function sort_li(a, b){
        return (Number($(b).find('a').data('value'))) <= (Number($(a).find('a').data('value'))) ? 1 : -1;
     }
     arrangeLiBasedOnDataValue();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text content of all of the anchor tags inside an Array which can be put in ascending numeric order using `Array.prototype.sort(a,b => return a-b)`. You can then remove all the `li` elements and replace them with new `li` elements in numeric order.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-value="8" title="8">8</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="9" title="9">9</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="10" title="10">10</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="11" title="11">11</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="12" title="12">12</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="13" title="13">13</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="14" title="14">14</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="8.5" title="8.5">8.5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="9.5" title="9.5">9.5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="10.5" title="10.5">10.5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-value="11.5" title="11.5">11.5</a></li>
<script>
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("li > a");
var nums = [];
for(let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
  nums[i] = parseFloat(anchors[i].textContent);
  anchors[i].parentNode.parentNode.remove(anchors[i].parentNode);
}
var orderedNums = nums.sort(function(a, b){
 return a-b;
});
for(let i = 0; i < orderedNums.length; i++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "<a href='#' data-value='"+orderedNums[i]+"' title='"+orderedNums[i]+"'>"+orderedNums[i]+"</a>";
  document.body.appendChild(li);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the elements inside the `ul` using `querySelectorAll`. Then create an array of objects. This object will have all the attribute and values of `a` tag

```js
function doSort() {
  let htmlDOM = document.querySelectorAll('.tt-options-swatch li a');
  // Creating an array of objects which has the values of the attribute
  //from a tag
  let domArray = [...htmlDOM].reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let obj = {
      href: curr.href,
      dataVal: curr.dataset.value,
      title: curr.title,
      text: +curr.innerHTML.trim() // converting string to number 
    }
    acc.push(obj)
    return acc;
  }, [])
   // now sorting by the text
  let sortedDom = domArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.text - b.text;
  })
  // creating a new dom 
  let newDOM = '';
  sortedDom.forEach(function(elem) {
    newDOM += `<li><a href = '${elem.href}'
                 data-value = '${elem.dataVal}'
                 title = '${elem.title}'
                 >${elem.text}</a></li>`

  })
  document.getElementsByClassName('tt-options-swatch')[0].innerHTML = newDOM
}
```

```html
<ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
  <li class="active"><a href="#" data-value="8" title="8">8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="9" title="9">9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="10" title="10">10</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="11" title="11">11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="12" title="12">12</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="13" title="13">13</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="14" title="14">14</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="8.5" title="8.5">8.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="9.5" title="9.5">9.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="10.5" title="10.5">10.5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-value="11.5" title="11.5">11.5</a></li>

</ul>

<button onclick='doSort()'>CLick to Sort</button>
```